# Can i find the driver (instant client) oracle/odbc for mac osx?

Tags: macos, oracle, odbc

I'm trying to find a way to connect ODBC to oracle XE, it works in windows and linux, but i don't find Instant Client Package - ODBC for MacOS (http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/intel-macsoft-096467.html)

You have any solution for that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Oracle ODBC driver is no longer supported for Mac. That's why it's not listed on the URL you posted.